# Laptop Screen Turns White On Start Up

Tags: laptop, display

G'day, I have a Toshiba L670 17" and sometimes when I turn the computer on, the screen will go white, but this only happens if the charger is not plugged in.
After the computer has booted into Windows, It normally doesn't turn white, however there is still the off chance that it will.
I was thinking about buying a new screen cable for it and see how it goes, but before I do, does anyone else have any suggestions as to what I could try?
Also note that when the screen is white and I plug an external monitor into the laptop, the external monitor works fine, so I'm confused as to if the motherboard is faulty or not.
When the computer is turning on and the charger is not plugged in, if I close the laptop lid and open it, there is a 50/50 chance that it works.
If I move the laptop screen up and down and bend it slightly the colors remain the same and works as expected.

Comment: If it depends on whether the computer is on the battery or getting AC from the wall (i.e. charger plugged in) then that means it's an electric related issue. You might want to take apart your laptop to clean it a bit, but only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: hey mate, thanks for your reply, yeah i should have mentioned, i pulled it apart and re seated the LCD cable and applied new thermal paste, I have ordered a new cable from ebay, So I guess in the new few days we will see what happens, fingers crossed x, after looking online but this seems to be a pretty common issue people have been having, there are saying to re seat the cable and it will fix it, not the case in my situation, so hopefully a new cable does the trick.

Comment: New cable has arrived and my laptops screen hasn't gone white since, I will wait until it goes white again before replacing it